# If an object is instantiated in the appDelegate does it live forever?

Tags: ios, dependency-injection, appdelegate

I'm working through a tutorial that uses a term called inverse dependency injection as stated by the author.  Basically its a a to-do list application which can instantiate an ItemStore object that keeps track of all to-do items, rearranging, etc.  In this tutorial we instantiated the ItemStore object in the AppDelegate which is accessed in a the UITableViewController via an unwrapped property of the UITableViewController.  My question is this, if the ItemStore object is instantiated in the AppDelegate, does it live for the entire lifecycle of the app?  And also if it does, since its not a singleton does this mean that each time I show the UITableViewController in the app is it creating a memory leak or retain cycle?

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        //create an ItemStore
        let itemStore = ItemStore()

        //now access the ItemsViewController and set its item store
        let itemsController = window!.rootViewController as! ItemsTableViewController
        itemsController.itemStore = itemStore
        //we just set the itemStore property of the ItemsTableViewController!  Yayy, WHEW!! Now when the ItemsTableViewController is accessed with that unwrapped ItemStore object then it will be set!!! WHHHHEEEEWWWWW!
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

Comment: A class member lives as long as the object owing it lives, a variable in a method only lives while the method is executed.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson so what I think you are saying is that when the method applicationDidEnterBackground of the appDelegate fires by placing the app in the background then this ItemStore object won't be living anymore?

Comment: Correct. It only exists in application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Understood and I'm appreciative.  I should have re-worded my question to ask if the ItemStore object continues to live if I show another viewController besides the one that has the dependency injection.  For example, if I go away to a another viewController and then show the ItemsTableViewController again will it show the same ItemStore object from before?

Comment: If it is the same instance you created in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: then yes but not if you have created a new view controller

Comment: @JoakimDanielson INTERESTING!!!!  So if I add new viewControllers to this project then is it safe to say that I will need to pass the ItemStore object between viewControllers using delegation?  Is that possible or recommended?

Comment: I think you mean dependency injection not delegation and yes it is recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Joakim already gives a pretty good answer.  We can access the `variable` from any class if it is declared as a class `attribute`.  The `AppDelegate` class has a `singleton` object.  We can access it by this way.

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let aVariable = appDelegate.someVariable
```

So it always returns the same object with same data and you can access it from any class you want but a variable in a method is only accessible by this method.

Comment: And now that Rumy has shown you how to access the app delegate from anywhere: don't do it. It violates the [Dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle). pass any dependency during initialising or through setters.